# Booting from a pendrive(USB) doesnt work !

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I've created bootable USB by some software and set my first boot device to USB but it doesn't booting.
It doesn't proceeds after showing "Verifying DMI pool data".

Comment: what software you used ?

Comment: have you tried Unetbootin ?

Comment: Now i can boot from a USB. Unetbootin is a bad one. I've done it with Universal USB Installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must modify how to start your computer: your hard disk dtive, your cd-dvd drive, your usb, and so on. Perhaps many computers allow to modify this list just pressing F2 at the moment of starting the machine.

Comment: I did this way but booting first of all the dvd drive. Simply burning the image on a dvd disk.